# Generate PDF with PDFSharp from HTML template and send to browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, webforms, httpresponse

I am currently writing an addition to a website that I made for work.  It generates a PDF from an HTML template and then serves it to the browser so that it can be printed off.

I created a small test that works perfectly.  The problem I am running into is when I coded a more complete test, nothing happens when I click the generate button.  In the first page when the page loads the PDF is created and shows in the browser.  On the second page I get nothing, and no error message which makes troubleshooting this difficult.  The code is almost identical between the two pages, so I am really confused as to what is happening.

I will post both versions of my code.  Hopefully you guys can figure out what is happening.

Working Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = Server.MapPath("/test.pdf");
        string html = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument my_pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html, PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter);
        my_pdf.Save(filePath);
        byte[] docStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", docStream.GetLength(0).ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(docStream);
        Response.End();
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Non Working Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmMain.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "900px");
        frmMain.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "auto");
        frmMain.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginRight, "auto");

        tblForm.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginRight, "auto");
        tblForm.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "auto");
    }
    protected void generate_pdf(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string html_page = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("/nice_letter.html"));
        string filePath = Server.MapPath($"/{RandomString(10, true)}.pdf");
        html_page = html_page.Replace("{{letter_date}}", txtLetterDate.Text);
        html_page = html_page.Replace("{{recipient_name}}", txtRecipientName.Text);
        html_page = html_page.Replace("{{patient_name}}", txtPatientName.Text);
        html_page = html_page.Replace("{{appointment_date}}", txtAppointmentDate.Text);
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument my_pdf = TheArtOfDev.HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp.PdfGenerator.GeneratePdf(html_page, PdfSharp.PageSize.Letter);
        my_pdf.Save(filePath);
        byte[] docStream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=letter.pdf");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", docStream.GetLength(0).ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(docStream);
        Response.End();
        System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
    }
    public string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase = false)  
    {
        Random _random = new Random();
        var builder = new StringBuilder(size);    
        char offset = lowerCase ? 'a' : 'A';  
        const int lettersOffset = 26;  
        for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)  
        {  
            var @char = (char)_random.Next(offset, offset + lettersOffset);  
            builder.Append(@char);  
        }
        return lowerCase ? builder.ToString().ToLower() : builder.ToString();  
    }
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
        <center><h1>Nice Letter</h1></center>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="smMain" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMain" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <table id="tblForm" runat="server">
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblLetterDate" Text="Letter Date: " runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtLetterDate" Width="150" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblRecipientName" Text="Recipient: " runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtRecipientName" Width="300" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblPatientName" Text="Patient Name: " runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtPatientName" Width="300" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><asp:Label ID="lblAppointmentDate" Text="Appointment Date: " runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                            <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtAppointmentDate" Width="150" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td><asp:Button ID="cmdCreatePDF" runat="server" Text="Create PDF" OnClick="generate_pdf" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check f12 in your browser, you're doing an ajax request, you have to read up how to catch the result, open in new window or something like that.
Also there's some error in the console, but it looks like the PDF is created just fine. Maybe you can just save the PDF to disk, and return a download link.

Comment: @Charles Thanks.  Yeah, I just did a test with another nuget package to generate PDF's because that one didn't support css, and I figured out that the ajax was killing the whole thing.  I am not gonna bother with catching the response, I am just gonna post the information to a new page and create the PDF there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.  Apparently it was because I was doing an ajax request via the update panels.  It works fine without the ajax.